# Formato de fechas de un select con Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una consulta de Eloquent que trae varios valores a través de un select, entre ellos algunas fechas. Luego el resultado de la consulta se pasa a un Export para ser descargados en una hoja de Excel. Hasta ahí va perfecto, pero me pidieron que las fechas tengan dos columnas en la hoja de Excel: una para colocar el año y el mes (YYYYMM) y en la otra solo el día (dd). Ya he trabajado con Carbon para los formatos, pero no se como formatear las fechas y de nuevo introducirlas en el resultado de la consulta.

Esta es mi consulta en Eloquent:

```
  // Busca el cliente enviado en el formulario y examina los datos
    $cliente = Cliente::find($request->get('cliente_id'));

    // Filtro de busqueda de las facturas
    $reportes = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '606')
    ->select('documento', 'bienes','tipo_bien', 'ncf', 'ncf_modificado','date_comp', 'date_pago',
            'tipo_bien', 'monto_servicios', 'monto_bienes',  'monto_total',  'itebis_fact',
            'itebis_retenido', 'itebis_sujeto', 'itebis_costo', 'itebis_adelantar', 'itebis_compras',
             'tipo_retencion', 'monto_retenido', 'isr', 'impuesto_consumo', 'otros_impuestos',
             'propina', 'forma_pago' )
    ->orderBy('created_at' ,'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Este es mi Export en Excel:

```
 // Descargar el archivo en formato Excel las facturas filtradas usando ReportesExport
        return (new ReportesExport($reportes))->download('Reporte.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `map` para modificar la collection

```
->get()->map(function ($reporte) {
    $date = Carbon::parse($reporte->date_pago);
    $reporte->date_pago = $date->format('Y').$date->format('m');
    $reporte->date_pago_dd = $date->format('d');
    return $reporte;
});
```